# BeanNameAutoProxyCreator setBeanNames regular expression not working?

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, spring-4, aspect

This is my `BeanNameAutoProxyCreator`:

```
@Bean
public BeanNameAutoProxyCreator beanNameAutoProxyCreator() {
    BeanNameAutoProxyCreator beanNameAutoProxyCreator = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
    beanNameAutoProxyCreator.setBeanNames("*service"); // If i put "*Service" instead, then i get an exception. 
    beanNameAutoProxyCreator.setInterceptorNames("loggingAdvice", "debugInterceptor");
    return beanNameAutoProxyCreator;
}

@Bean
public LoggingAdvice loggingAdvice() {
    return new LoggingAdvice();
}

@Bean
public DebugInterceptor debugInterceptor() {
    return new DebugInterceptor();
}
```

And this is my ClientService bean:

```
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public ClientService clientService() {
    return new ClientServiceImpl(this.clientDAO);
}
```

So, i don't know why, when i call `setBeanNames("*service")` is not setting properly the interceptors. If i put "*Service" then i get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68 cannot be cast to org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.example.movies.service.Application.main(Application.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68 cannot be cast to org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68 cannot be cast to org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6264082.mvcConversionService(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:343)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6264082.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6264082$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$37e805df.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6264082.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

And if I put "clientService" it works fine but that is not what I want. I want that all beans that ends with "Service" then be intercepted. But for some reason, "*Service" is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to set

```
beanNameAutoProxyCreator.setProxyTargetClass(true);
```

so that Spring uses CGLIB to proxy your instances. Otherwise, it uses JDK proxies which only support interfaces.

Note that you're currently proxying (knowingly or unknowingly) beans that may be registered by your Web MVC configuration. These might not necessarily support proxying (`final` classes for example).