# Spring boot migration : non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to migrate old spring application (spring + jsp for presentation layer + hibernate) to spring boot.
Everything is migrated without problems unless I add dispatcherServlet and add @EnableWebMvc. I got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService called as a bean reference for type [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
at fr.etai.driivin.SpringBootWebApplication.main(SpringBootWebApplication.java:31) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService called as a bean reference for type [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method WebMvcConfigurationSupport.mvcConversionService called as a bean reference for type [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:402) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fdda9fb.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getInterceptors(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:253) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fdda9fb.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerMapping$45(<generated>) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fdda9fb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b4754450.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2fdda9fb.requestMappingHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

I have Aop configuration. I have seen in this thread (http://thecopsjava.blogspot.fr/2016/08/non-compatible-bean-instance-of-type.html) and I have set proxyTargetClass to true.

Comment: I resolved this issue by following this solution of this thread:
[beanNameAutoProxyCreator.setProxyTargetClass(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29397992/7931933)